# Copy Range Based on Cell Data

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to copy a column based on cell data. I want any cells within the column to be copied over as long as they actually contain data of some kind, any empty cells should be ignored.

I have tried `=filter()` to no avail as the formula does not recognise `!=""` as `blank`

Comment: `<>""` instead of `!=""`

Comment: @MaxMakhrov Thank you, I had to make a slight tweak but everything works perfectly now! Thanks again. These small difference in code logic are so annoying.

Comment: Your welcome! I guess you may delete the question as syntax errors are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Query?

```
=Query(A:A;"Select A where A<>''")
```